# Metro App Conditionally Disable AppBar RightTapped event

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, appbar

Whenever a right click is detected on a metro app, the `AppBar` is displayed.

How do I **cancel/disable/prevent** the `AppBar` from showing if the `RightTapped` event is triggered by right clicking on a specific control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RightTapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.righttapped.aspx) is a routed event and [its event args](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.righttappedroutedeventargs.aspx) includes the [Handled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.righttappedroutedeventargs.handled.aspx) property.  So in whatever control you are processing the event, add the following code at the end to suppress the AppBar.

```
e.Handled = true;
```